# Using python / openpyxl filter sheet on 1 column containing a specific string and copying filtered results to another sheet

Tags: python-3.x, excel, openpyxl

Hi I'm trying to filter a sheet on 1 column containing a specific string (let's say it's ABC). I am running the following code. It runs without error but doesn't produce the expected results (copying X amount of records to the 2nd tab in the workbook)

```
sheet = wb ['TEST']
sheet2 = wb ['TEST_FORMATTED']
        
for row in sheet.iter_rows(values_only=True):
    if row[13] == 'ABC':
        sheet2.append(row)    
    
 wb.save('TESTWB.xlsx')
```

Comment: Please explain what isn't working as you expect it to.

Comment: There is no data in the 2nd tab that I am trying to copy the data to.. when I expect  it be a x amount of rows and columns of data

Comment: Then presumably the condition isn't being met.